# How to lie down Tyvek as a ground sheet?

Tags: tyvek, tent-footprints

I have Tyvek 1443R and I realized I don't know which side should I put it down -- I would like that any vapor goes from above to the ground, but not from the ground up (so it will breathe out, not in).

One side of Tyvek 1443R is smooth/slippery, and the other is rather rough (compared to the first one).

So in which direction vapor goes -- from smooth to rough, or vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both is the answer to this. Tyvek 1443r is bonded oleofin, so it is all one material, just one side has been pressed to bond it all together.